# Simple proxy in Java

Tags: java, proxy

I want to build a simple proxy (127.0.0.3:1234) to transfer my database connections from my app to specific database servers (127.0.0.1:1234 and 127.0.0.2:1234). Is that possible in Java? I'm worry about the persistence connections between dbs and application...

Answer (score 0):

If you want a proxy to load balance between two TCP connection, that is relatively simple. I suggest you try it and post a question when you run into an issue.

> I'm worry about the persistence connections between dbs and application...

You don't need to worry.

Comment: by using java socket, i can open a connection, then can u suggest me how to redirect to destination ? Thank you very much

Comment: You have a ServerSocket listening on `127.0.0.3:1234` and when you get a connection you connect to either `127.0.0.1:1234` or `127.0.0.1:1234` You start two threads, one which copies everything from the incoming connection to the outgoing connection and one for copying everything from the outgoing connection tot he incoming connection.  There is no magic to bind two sockets together.

Comment: hmmh, do u have any example :( I only know Socket, I googled something about ServerSocket but it only accepts the port only